# Binding to main datacontext, not of row

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I want to bind itemsource of column to main datacontext of xaml

Before I had it done like that:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Type" DataMemberBinding="{Binding VehicleCondition}" ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding VehicleConditions,Source={StaticResource ShowroomLog}}"  />
```

but I removed

from app.xaml

and in showroomlogview.xaml I have declaration

```
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinITApp" DataContext="{Binding ShowroomLog, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

No it doesn't find me vehicleconditions, but I don't know how I can change this code to have this correct.

How can I do id?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using

```
"{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ShowroomLog.Handlers}"
```